# pandas get_dummies how to remember which value become which new category?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

it seems quick an ease to one-hot-encoding multiple categorical variables at once using get_dummies method, but how to remember which one is which so that my test data have the same feature as my training data? for example:

My training dataset has a CATEGORICAL feature:

```
   X
   cat
   dog
   lion
   lion
```

after get_dummies, I got something like this:

```
   X_1   X_2   X_3
    1     0     0
    0     1     0
    0     0     1
    0     0     1
```

after training model, I am ready to test my awesome magic model and here is the test data:

```
   X
   cat
   cat
   lion
```

if I apply the pd.get_dummies methods, I will get something like this:

```
   X_1      X_2
   1       0
   1       0
   0       1
```

which will be inconsistent with my train data features and i simply can't apply my model to the test data.

any suggestions so that I can get some like the following ?

```
   X_1   X_2   X_3
    1     0     0
    1     0     0
    0     0     1
```

How can I get a fit and transform functionality? again, I have over 50 categorical features and I can't apply LabelEncoder and then One_Hot_Encoder to them one by one.

Any suggestion? thank you.

Comment: Short version: define categories upfront and cast the dtype as category. Now when you call get_dummies pandas will generate columns for all categories even if they don't exist in that particular dataset.

Comment: Oh wow... there's a dupe... and the solution is wonderful

Comment: @ayhan, the answer in the pose you mentioned is quite convenient if there are handful of features, what if there are over 50 category features...any alternatives?

Comment: You can use [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

Comment: Also, one more thing you need to consider is the opposite scenario of what you described? In which test data has more categorical variables than the train.

Comment: very good point.

Answer (score 0):

I use get_dummies for all data, after that I split it into training and testing.

Comment: Sometimes this is not a feasible option... then what?

Comment: nope, won't work in real world